# How do I create a new column for my dataframe whose values are maps made up of values from different columns?

Tags: pyspark

I've seen similar questions but haven't been able to find exactly what I need and have been struggling to figure out if I can manage to do what I want without using a UDF.

Say I start with this dataframe:

```
+---+---+---+
| pk|  a|  b|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  1|
|  2|  4|  2|
+---+---+---+
```

I want the resulting dataframe to look like

```
+----------------+---+
|              ab| pk|
+----------------+---+
|[A -> 2, B -> 1]|  1|
|[A -> 4, B -> 2]|  2|
+----------------+---+
```

Where `A` and `B` are names that correspond to `a` and `b` (I guess I can fix this with an alias, but currently now I'm using a UDF that returns a map of `{'A': column a value, 'B': column b value}`)

Is there any way to accomplish this using create_map or otherwise without a UDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create_map` takes arguments as `key, value, key, value ...`, for your case:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.select(
  f.create_map(f.lit('A'), f.col('a'), f.lit('B'), f.col('b')).alias('ab'), 
  f.col('pk')
).show()
+----------------+---+
|              ab| pk|
+----------------+---+
|[A -> 2, B -> 1]|  1|
|[A -> 4, B -> 2]|  2|
+----------------+---+
```